# How can I install NikGApps on a fully unlocked Android 12 system without being refused by signature verification?

Tags: google-play-store, rom-flashing, gapps

I have an Android 12 installation loaded onto an ARM SoC "super" SBC (Firefly ITX-3588J) and want to try and get Google Play working on it, as the stock A12 image does not come with it. Because this is a full computer system and not a smartphone, I both have full access to the memory, bootloader, root, etc. yet also, pretty much all instructions I've found online for installing things like that seem to presume a smartphone with varying degrees of restriction.

My best approach so far has been to get the package "NikGApps" (), instead of Open GApps, because the latter does not currently support Android 12, but the former does. However, I have no idea how to load the package into the system. Looking it up, most people on smartphones seem to do this using something called TWRP, but TWRP apparently *does not support Android 12*. Yet obviously the author of that package somehow intended for it to be installed on Android 12, but the instructions they provide for doing that are *extremely* terse and simply say "flash" it to the board with no details of *how* you do that.

Further digging *seems* to suggest the answer is to use `adb sideload` after booting to the stock (i.e. not TWRP) recovery mode, however the problem here is that when I do that I get an `E:Signature verification failed` error and the system refuses to complete the installation (at somewhere between 40% and 50%, I believe 47%). Presumably, and from what I can gather online, this is a problem relating to the fact it is not some officially "blessed" package for the Android system (i.e. it has to be signed and OKed by some "trustworthy" source).

And so my question is, is there some way around that? How can I install this package successfully and correctly?

Comment: You don't need TWRP recovery, you just need a custom recovery that allows to disable signature verification to flash the GApps package.

Comment: @Robert: How do I get that for Android 12?

Comment: Previous question for additional context: [How can one install Google Play Services on an Android-running device that does not have it by default?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247931/44325)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using OrangePi 5 and had the same problem.

> E:Signature verification failed error

Based on my research, this error is caused by not unlocking the bootloader.

Here are the steps I took, hope it helps you.

1. Get adb/fastboot-tool (I assume you already know)

   - https://androidmtk.com/download-minimal-adb-and-fastboot-tool
2. Boot the device into **fake** fastboot mode (fastbootd or fastboot daemon)

   ```
   adb reboot fastboot
   ```
3. After the device has booted into fastbootd mode, use the following command to check if Windows has installed the fastboot driver or not.

   ```
   fastboot devices
   ```

   If you do not see the device list display, or **-waiting for any device-** error, then download and install the fastboot driver according to the following link:

   - https://github.com/fawazahmed0/Latest-adb-fastboot-installer-for-windows
   - https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/official-tool-windows-adb-fastboot-and-drivers-15-seconds-adb-installer-v1-4-3.2588979/
4. Boot into **real** fastboot mode (bootloader mode)

   ```
   fastboot bootloader
   ```
5. Unlock the bootloader

   ```
   fastboot flashing unlock
   ```
6. After this step, you should try flashing Gapps again

   ```
   adb sideload gapps.zip
   ```

**Note:** I haven't actually unlocked the bootloader yet, because my device freezes when booting into bootloader mode (still researching).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have found a solution for how to install Gapps for Orange Pi 5 Android.

It turns out that to unlock Android's bootloader, we have to enable the "OEM unlock" feature which is not implemented (SCB's Android images).

This is a link to the step-by-step guide of Discord user **snowdrag2020**: https://discord.com/channels/934722269522059335/1040242609626554408/1056234247628800101

I just copy/paste it here for a better search engine result.

> 1. Install Aurora Store. Search for “Device ID” and install
> 2. Search for firefox and install.
> 3. Open firefox, download
>    https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases/download/v25.2/Magisk-v25.2.apk and install.
> 4. Open Magisk App. It will tell you that you have installed MagiskApp but not yet Magisk core. Press Install Magisk and reboot.
> 5. Open firefox, download https://sourceforge.net/projects/magiskgapps/files/android-12L-ALPHA/17.10.2022/MagiskGApps-a.12L.BASIC.10.16.2022.zip/download remember to download a12 version not a13 since orange pi 5 rom is Android 12.
> 6. Open Magisk App, it will warn you about a duplicated ‘su’ is found, ignore it.
> 7. Select “module”. Select “Install from Storage”. Choose the MagiskGApp a12 zip file. It will install it and then reboot itself.
> 8. This reboot will take much longer than it used to be since GAPP is being loaded.
> 9. After reboot, try open Google Play Store and click “Sign In”. It will warn you your device is NOT Google Play Protected Certified. I forgot the steps, just follow the steps to get to a page to register your device.
> 10. Open “Device ID” , find the entry of “Google Services Framework (GSF)”, copy the HEX id to the registration page and register.
> 11. For my own experience, it takes ~5 mins to complete the registration even after it tells you your device is registered. Keep trying signing in the Google play store until it works.
> 12. Congratulation, your GAPPs is ready.

**All credits goes to him!**